# Angular Use Function in Container Context

Tags: angularjs, containers, ngfor

I want to set up a checkbox structure and I want to handle it dynamically. I have an object response returned from my service. However, when I use this function in context, I get a string return and I cannot use ngFor.

**form.demo.component.ts**

```
   getElementChoicesByNKey(nkey:string):choiceModel[]{
     var element = this.findInComponentsByNKey(nkey);
     var res = element.Choices;
     return res;
   }
```

this function gives the correct return.

**form.demo.component.html**

```
...
                        <ng-container *ngIf="item.Type == 'Choice'">
                          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="choiceTheme; context:{ Id: item.Id, Label: item.Label, Choices: getElementChoicesByNKey(item.Id) }"></ng-container> 
                        </ng-container>
...
                <ng-template #choiceTheme let-Id="Id" let-Label="Label" let-Choices="Choices">
                  <nz-form-item>                      
                    <nz-form-label nzFor="Id">{{Label}}</nz-form-label>
                    <nz-form-control [formControlName]="Id" nzErrorTip="{{ 'form.requiredText' | translate }}"> 
                      <p>{{Choices.length}}</p>
                      <div *ngFor="let item of Choices">
                        <p>test</p>
                      </div>                               
                    </nz-form-control>
                  </nz-form-item>            
                </ng-template>
...
```

here Choices appears as string and won't let me use ngFor. I am getting an error as below.

> Cannot find a differ supporting object '[
> { label: 'Apple', value: 'Apple', checked: true },
> { label: 'Pear', value: 'Pear', checked: false },
> { label: 'Orange', value: 'Orange', checked: false }   ]' of type 'string'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.

What is the point I missed? Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use
`*ngFor="let item of getChoices(Choices)"` in template
and in `component.ts`

```
getChoices(choiceStr) {
    return JSON.parse(choiceStr);
}
```

Since you are getting `Choices` as a string, parse the string to an array inorder for `ngFor` to work